# page token youtube api v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to do pagination with youtube api v3 (/videos?).

```
My request uri - https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key={APP_KEY}&part=snippet&maxResults=50&chart=mostPopular&videoCategoryId=10
```

But in response I didn't see `nextPageToken` field.

If I send `maxResult` field which set in 49 (not 50 like first request). In response I can find `nextPageToken` field and count of items in search - 200. BUT, when I send new request for second part of search - in response I have only 15 items (must be 49) and haven't `nextPageToken` field, only `previousPageToken`.

Thank.

Comment: Does the channel you're querying have more than 64 videos?

Comment: Yes. It is request for most popular videos on youtube. There are more than 200.

Comment: What's the chance you can post your code?

Comment: I wrote my request's link at the top of post. It's all. You can use fiddler for check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer, but too much to put into a comment:

Using

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=20

to collect the `nextPageToken`, then doing a second and finally third time, the same is happening to me.

I then removed the maxResults param, thinking this might not be doing what I thought, and patiently worked through until I hit the same place as before (was using maxResults = 20)..and no more `nextPageToken`, even though the "totalResults": 200

Can only think:

1. throttled to only give you 40 results (in which case it should indicate so)
2. bug